# What is a Java example of the "private constructor capture" idiom?

Tags: java

Can some one explain to me the **private constructor capture idiom** with an example and point out where we actually need / do not need this kind of design?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The aim is to capture a temporary value during construction.

An example is given in Solution 53 of [*Java Puzzlers*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/JavaTM-Puzzlers-Pitfalls-Corner-ebook/dp/B001U5VJVS/):

```
public class MyThing extends Thing {
    private final int arg;

    public MyThing() {
        this(SomeOtherClass.func());
    }

    private MyThing(int i) {
        super(i);
        arg = i;
   }
}
```

In this case, we want to capture and store the parameter that we wish to pass to the superclass constructor.  In order to do so, we create a private helper constructor, which our public constructor then calls.

Comment: is this a good idea to capture the state of the object when the constructor runs and hasn't finished executing yet ?I mean the object could be in an inconsistent state ?

Comment: @Subhra: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Which object could be in an inconsistent state?

Comment: the object that is being constructed itself ? Isn't the object supposedly in a consistent state only after it has been properly constructed .

Comment: @Subhra: Indeed.  But why does that matter in this situation?  All we're doing is constructor chaining.

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter since arg is final and private ?

Comment: @Subhra: Yes.  Constructor chaining (i.e. one constructor calling another) is a fairly common pattern in Java.

Comment: In the book it is mentioned that this pattern is thread safe - why ? Also does one _need_ to declare the constructor private (for thread safety or other reasons) ? Please don't answer in a comment just edit your answer

Answer (score 10):

An explanation is given with an example in [Java Concurrency In Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) chapter 4 section 4.3.5.

```
public class SafePoint {
    private int x, y;

    private SafePoint(int[] a) {
        this(a[0], a[1]);
    }

    public SafePoint(SafePoint p) {
        this(p.get());
    }

    public SafePoint(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public synchronized int[] get() {
        return new int[] { x, y };
    }

    public synchronized void set(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

The private constructor exists to avoid the race condition that would occur if the copy constructor were implemented as this(p.x, p.y).

What does it mean is, if you did not have a private constructor and you implement copy constructor in following way:

```
public SafePoint(SafePoint p) {
    this(p.x, p.y);
}
```

Now assume that thread A is having the access to SafePoint **p** is executing above copy constructor's this(p.x, p.y) instruction and at the unlucky timing another thread B also having access to SafePoint **p** executes setter set(int x, int y) on object **p**. Since your copy constructor is accessing **p**'s **x** and **y** instance variable directly without proper locking it could see inconsistent state of object **p**.

Where as the private constructor is accessing **p**'s variables **x** and **y** through getter which is synchronized so you are guaranteed to see consistent state of object **p**.